# jquery listbox validation

Tags: jquery, forms, listbox

I'm using Jquery and html and I just ran into an issue with list menu (multiple) validation. The issue is that I cannot(/do not know how to) count the number of selections the user has made. I tried adding ':' at the end of every option value and then split the text into an array, and it did work but then I mess my database.

```
  var int_country= $('#int_country :selected').text();
  listLength = int_country.split(":");

if (listLength.length > 16){

var i = listLength.length -1;
alert ("You have selected " + i + " countries. \nPlease select 15 or less international countries!");
    $('#int_country').focus();
    return false;
}
```

Any suggestions how to get around this?

Comment: how exactly do you "mess your database"?

Comment: well, the code up there doesn't have to do anything with the database but I am inserting the same value that is on the list box in the database, which includes ":" and you can imagine the rest of the complications that might derive from that when joining tables and other things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$('#int_country :selected').length` to get the count